# Is there an attribute to turn off serialisation for fields in a custom object (DataContractJsonSerializer)

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I am using the DataContractJsonSerializer class to serialise my objects to JSON.

Is there an attribute I can use on fields in my custom objects (C#) that will turn off serialisation for that one particular field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, there is a way: IgnoreDataMemberAttribute

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ignoredatamemberattribute.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656732.aspx for full documentation.

Comment: That second link was great: "All public fields, and properties with public get and set methods are serialized, unless you apply the IgnoreDataMemberAttribute attribute to that member."

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [DataContractAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx) to decorate your class, you will then be required to use the [DataMemberAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.aspx) to mark the fields/properties that you want to have serialized.  I don't think that there is any attribute that can turn off serialization of a public property/field on a class without the DataContractAttribute.  MSDN has a [tutorial on how to serialize data as JSON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx).